# In GIMP 2.0 can you set new layers to be created at the bottom of the image instead of the top?

Tags: gimp

Currently, when I create a new layer, it's at the very top of a rather tall canvas. All of my new layers need to be at the bottom (to make use of the "growth chart" background layer).

Is there a way to have them be created at the bottom of the canvas instead of the top, or is the only option to drag them all the way down manually?

Answer (score 0):

Layers are created just above the current layer. If you want to consistently create layers at the bottom of the stack, add a transparent placeholder layer at the bottom of the stack and make it active just before creating a new layer.

Comment: Does the lower, placeholder layer have to be bigger than the new layer, or can it be just a few pixels high?

Comment: Size is pretty much irrelevant.